# How do I set an Attrib to the label and not the element in a zend form

Tags: php, label, zend-form, setattribute

Usually I would set up a send element by using the following

```
$question = new Zend_Form_Element_Text ("question");
$question->setLabel("Question")
  ->setAttrib('class', 'bob');
```

Here I have set a class around an element but how do I set it for the label instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ZF Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html):

```
$label = $element->getDecorator('label');
$label->setOption('class', 'bob');
```